# Add "Select All" to custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, select

Is it possible to add a "Select All" to a custom taxonomy for my custom post type? A project I'm working on requires the option to be able to select all of the taxonomy terms. While I could go through and manually click each term, it becomes quite cumbersome when I have several hundred terms.

I haven't tried anything yet, as I'm not sure how to go about it....is it something I can add to my `functions.php` or is it something that can be accomplished with javascript?

Comment: Javascript. I am fairly sure that makes the question off-topic here though.

Comment: Thanks @s_ha_dum. I'll post this elsewhere, unless you're able to move it for me?

Comment: I think you could also do it with PHP. In my Radio Buttons for Taxonomies plugin I filtered `get_terms` to add a "No Term" option to the checklist. You could add an "All terms" checkbox and then process that on save post.

Comment: @helgatheviking that sounds like it might work. Could you offer more information, and maybe an example of how I might accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: @NWTech : no, I can't move it. Mods can though. helgatheviking is right though. You could rebuild that meta_box to have another field. The Javascript solution is going to be the simpler solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to rebuild the metabox... you can just add a *pseudo* term via the `get_terms` filter.  This will add an "All Terms" term to your checkbox list, (assuming a hierarchical taxonomy).

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'wpa104168_all_terms', 10, 3 );

function wpa104168_all_terms ( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ){

        if ( is_admin() && function_exists( 'get_current_screen' ) && ! is_wp_error( $screen = get_current_screen() ) && in_array( $screen->base, array( 'post', 'edit-post', 'edit' ) ) ) {

            if( in_array( 'genre', ( array ) $taxonomies ) ) {

                $all_terms = __( 'All Genres' );

                $all = (object) array( 'term_id' => 'all', 'slug' => 'all', 'name' => $all_terms, 'parent' => '0' );

                $terms['all'] = $all;
            }
        }
        return $terms;
    }
```

And this runs on `save_post` tests for the presence of that pseudo term and then assigns all the terms in that taxonomy to that particular post.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpa104168_save_all_terms', 10, 3 );

function wpa104168_save_all_terms ( $post_id ){

// verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization.

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'update-post_' . $post_id )) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // verify if this is an auto save routine. If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Check permissions
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;
    } else {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
    }

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
   if ( isset( $_POST['tax_input']['genre'] ) && is_array( $_POST['tax_input']['genre'] ) && in_array( 'all', $_POST['tax_input']['genre'] ) ){

    $args = array( 'hide_empty'    => false );
        $terms = get_terms( 'genre', $args );


        if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){

            foreach ( $terms as $term ){
                $update[] = $term->slug;
            }

            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $update, 'genre' );

        }

   }



    return $post_id;

}
```

But a scripted solution is a lot simpler.  Doesn't need to be loaded on every admin page, but I'll leave that to you to sort out.

Clarification: change `genrechecklist` to the appropriate taxonomy name.... `{$taxonomy}checklist`

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'wpa104168_js_solution' );

function wpa104168_js_solution(){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('ul#genrechecklist').append('<li><label class="selectit"><input type="checkbox" class="toggle-all-terms"/> Check All</label>');

    $('.toggle-all-terms').on('change', function(){
        $(this).closest('ul').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked );
    });

});
</script>

<?php }
```

Comment: Perfect! The scripted solution worked great....it did take me a minute to figure out why it didn't work at first, until I realized I had to change `'ul#genrechecklist'` to the proper ID of my list. Thanks again!

Comment: Forgot to point that out... good point for anyone coming after. I wanted to toggle the label between 'Check all' and 'uncheck all', but the markup is weird and I didn't feel like figuring it out.